# annotate svn changes

Tags: svn

I am not sure if this is possible. Let's say that now I work or several files. My work is now done but I am offline and cannot make any changes. Is it possible to somehow annotate the current change log so I can continue working on other files?

In other words this is what I want to achieve

1. Work on some files
2. Annotate my work "new feature 1"
3. Work on some files
4. Annotate my work "new feature 2"
5. Go online
6. Commit
7. Now the server has logs for "new feature 1" and "new feature 2" with the appropriate changelog.

Comment: Note: in version control, the *annotate* term is normally used for what Subversion calls *blame*.

Answer (score 2):

There're two similar features, normally called [shelving](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3625) and [checkpointing](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3626), that could help you. None of them are currently implemented in Subversion. They are [being discussed](http://subversion.apache.org/roadmap.html) for future releases.

I've heard some developers use a distributed version control system (such as Git or Mercurial) as a workaround. They use it to keep track of local changes and then commit to the main Subversion repository when done.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not supported by SVN. You could make a diff from featuere 1. Revert your changes, implement feature 2 and make another diff and revert. Later you can import diff1 and commit it and diff2 and commit it. But honesty doing this would be really silly.

What you want is to use a version control like GIT where you can do local commits...